# PHP - Basic login check?

Tags: php, html, authentication

So, I'm trying to make a **VERY BASIC** login with PHP:

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $users = array("Billy", "Bob");
    $passes = array("billy123", "pass1234");

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($users); $i++) {
        $user = $i;
        if ($username === $users[$i]) {
            if ($password === $passes[$user]) {
                echo "Logged in as " .$users[$user];
            }
        }
        else if ($username !== $users[$i] && $password !== $passes[$i]) {
            echo "Login failed";
        }
    }
?>
```

I can't post the picture but it prints `"Logged in as BillyLogin failed"` exactly like that. And when I login as Bob it says `"Logged in as BobLogin failed"` I have no idea why though I can't seem to figure it out. Could someone explain what's going on and tell me how to fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course this happens, because for *every* username/password combination that is *not* a match, you echo out “Login failed” …

What you want to do instead, is loop through the whole array to see if there is a match – and *only* output “Login failed” *after* the loop if there was none.

```
$login_successful = false;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($users); $i++) {
    if ($username === $users[$i] && $password === $passes[$i]) {
        echo "Logged in as " .$users[$i];
        $login_successful = true;
        break; // no need to continue the loop here, so we break out of it
    }
}
if (!$login_successful) {
    echo "Login failed";
}
```

---

And since this will break if for some reason your `$users` and `$passes` arrays will not have the same amount of entries for any reason at some point, you should look into using a more suitable data structure as well – could f.e. be

```
$login_credentials = array(
  arrays('username' => 'Billy', 'password' => 'billy123'),
  arrays('username' => 'Bob',   'password' => 'pass1234'),
);
```

That is more concise, and easier to loop through as well:

```
$login_successful = false;
foreach ($login_credentials as $login_credential) {
    if ($username === $login_credential['username'] && $password === $login_credential["password"]) {
        echo 'Logged in as ' . $username;
        $login_successful = true;
        break; // no need to continue the loop here, so we break out of it
    }
}
if (!$login_successful) {
    echo 'Login failed';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The root if your problem is that you are not breaking out of the loop after someone has been authenticated, so it still checks against everyone else in the loop and will echo out the login status each iteration. What you want is to cache the logged in user id and if someone logs in, set the user id and break the loop. If the user id is set after the loop, they are logged in, otherwise they are not.

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $users = array("Billy", "Bob");
    $passes = array("billy123", "pass1234");

    $user_id=-1;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($users); $i++)
    {
        if ($username === $users[$i] && $password === $passes[$i])
        {
            $user_id=$i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if($user_id>=0)
    {
        echo "Logged in as " .$users[$user_id];
    }else
    {
        echo "Login failed";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the code below:

```
$username = $_POST['user'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];
$user["Bob"]="pass";
if ($username==$user[$username]){
echo "Authenticated";
} else {
echo "bad password";
}
```